# Javascript in Joomla article or module not executed

Tags: javascript, joomla

I want to use a piece of Javascript to filter tables. I tested the code without CMS and it worked perfectly. However, when I move it to Joomla te Javascript is not recognized/executed. I guess something is blocking or conflicting.

I tried adding the code with Sourcerer and also added it in a module with Flexi code. However, no effect. I read some other posts about this on Stackoverflow, but this was not relevant or no solution.

It's not a programm like RS Firewall that's blocking, and I have also checked the settings of JCE and the article options. All rights for admitting Javascript are okay.

What am I missing here? How can I get it to work?

This is the code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
if (td) {
if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
} 
}
}
</script>
```

As said, I tested the whole code also outside Joomla and the code itself looks okay. So the combination with Joomla makes it a problem.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Edit:
I created a test page: [test filter table](https://www.schoolholidayseurope.eu/filter-test) 
The Javascript snippet is around line 702 in the source.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the generated table id by inspecting HTML

Comment: Does the JavaScript appear in the source code of your page at all? The script does only contain a function which itself is useless. Did you include the code which calls this function as well?

Comment: Thanks. Yes,the table id is the same. And yes the code is in the source of the page. This is the exact code I placed: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Can you share a link to that site?

Comment: @SvenBluege I added a test url above. Thanks so far!

Comment: @Jason This site contains at least one JavaScript error: if(window.pageYOffset>=&&window.innerWidth>750). That might be something your template is causing.

Comment: @SvenBluege Thanks. That's part of the menu I think. I don't believe that's causing the problem. I also tested another template, but the problem remains.

Comment: @Jason can you provide a link which does not throw a JavaScript error? Just to rule this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is petty simple. You included the necessary code but forgot to call it. The w3c example contains an event binding which I don't see in your source code.

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
```

Your code:

```
<input id="myInput" title="Type in a name" type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." />
```

You need to call the function `myFunction()` somewhere. Otherwise, nothing happens. If you can't add this onkeyup directly to the input field, you can use this JavaScript snippet as well:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#myInput').on('keyup', myFunction);
});
```

Comment: For some reason onkeyup got scripted out of the code. I totally didn't see that. After placing the whole input-line between sourcerer tags ({source}) it was solved. That was enough! Thanks!